# Do not understand the equation to calculate effectiveness of shielding gamma radiation

Tags: radiation

I am studying for the OHST exam and do not understand the solution to a example in my text book.  The equation is for calculating the effectiveness of shielding for gamma radiation.

Text Book:
Safety Professionals Reference and Study Guide 2nd Ed
W. David Yates
Page 576

$$I=I_o e^{-ux}$$

where:

$I$ = Intensity after shielding,

$I_o$= Original intensity,

$u$ = linear absorption coefficient of material,

$x$ = shielding thickness

Problem setup:

\begin{align}
I&=(35{\rm\,mrem/h})e^{-1.23 \times 5}
\\
 I&=(35\rm\,mrem/h)(0.002)
\\
I&=0.075\rm\,mrem/h
\end{align}

How do I get the (0.002) ?

Comment: Could you please properly edit the data in your problem setup: as it stands it quite hard to understand the various symbols and what they refer to.  For instance what is the value of $u$?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you're looking at a $35\rm\,mrem/h$ source, and shielding it using some material whose $e$-folding length $r_0 = 1/u = 1/(1.23\rm\,m^{-1})=0.813\,m$.  You have $x=5\rm\,m$ of this stuff, so your shielding factor is $\exp(-ux) = \exp(-6.15) = 0.002\,133$

Answer (score 0):

> > How do I get the (0.002) ?

A picture that's worth a 1000 words:

[image]